# How to customize the icon displayed on facebook when posting a url onto wall

Tags: facebook

I'd like to achieve basically the same thing as question:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19454/how-to-customize-icons-used-by-facebook-wall

As it did not get any answer, I'm asking the question here.

We are managing a facebook page and a web site. When we post a link from our website onto facebook an icon is grabbed from the site. Is there a way to tell facebook which icon to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Open Graph meta tags so Facebook knows what title/description/image to use. The quickest way to do this is to use the generator at 'step 2' on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - this will produce a set of tags

You should probably read the entire 'Facebook for Websites' document to see what you can do - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/